# D3 Tree Graph Modified Data Model

Tags: d3.js

I'm hoping to get  opinions on what would be a good data model to drawing something like d3 tree graph. Tree graph won't work for me as is because I have scenarios where a child node could be linked with two parent nodes, sometimes, the parent nodes from different levels of hierarchy. I'm planning to modify d3 tree graph to use a different data model, and here's where I'd really appreciate expert opinions. Following is a simple representation of what I think the data model could be. One is hierarchical model and the other is flat. Has anyone actually meddled with d3 tree data model? Any help/opinions are greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance for the help!

```
var hierarchicalData = [
  {
    "id": "n1",
    "children": [
      {
        "id": "n1-a",
        "children":[
          {
            "id": "n1-a-1"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": "n1-b",
        "children":[
          {
            "id": "n1-b-1"
          }
        ]
      }      
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "n2",
    "children": [
      {
        "id": "n2-a",
        "children":[
          {
            "id": "n2-a-1"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }  
];
```

The following is a flat representation of the exact same hierarchical model but contains "level" that represents hierarchy.

```
{
  "n1":{
    "level": 0,
    "children": ["n1-a", "n1-b"],    
  },
  "n1-a":{
    "level": 1,
    "children":["n1-a-1"]
  },
  "n1-a-1":{
    "level": 2,
    "children":[]
  },  
  "n1-b":{
    "level": 1,
    "children":["n1-b-1"]
  },
  "n1-b-1":{
    "level": 2,
    "children":[]
  },  
  "n2":{
    "level": 0,
    "children": ["n2-a"]
  },
  "n2-a":{
    "level": 1,
    "children": ["n2-a-1"]
  },
  "n2-a-1":{
    "level": 2,
    "children":[]
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If a child node can have more than one parent, then it's not a tree graph by definition.
There are several UI approaches you may take if you want to have a tree but it really depends on what you're trying to accomplish.

I worked with d3 tree to present a company Org-chart.
Several companies have employees with a direct manager and secondary manager.
What we did is showing the connection only to the direct manager.
But we presented the link to the other manager on mouse-over on the employee node.
This is more of a UI solution than a data model solution and there are many other possibilities.

Another option is to do what My-heritage did with family tree. They're showing both parents of each node, but only one of them is connected to the rest of the tree presented.

Comment: Thank you for your response, @Tomer Sela. I agree that whatI'm trying to accomplish is not tree by definition. I'd like to use d3 tree from a visual representation standpoint. I apologize if I was not clear in mentioning why tree won't work for me. A child could have more than one parent (not in the same hierarchy as like an org chart). Family Tree structure might work with some more changes to it. This is the reason that I'm trying to build a robust data model that can scale.